# libertineotf and xelatex - bold smallcaps broken?

Tags: fonts, xetex, bold, small-caps, libertine

It seems like bold smallcaps don't work with `libertineotf` any longer? I am currently adjusting an old template which I was using with `pdflatex`, and I need those bold small caps:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{libertineotf}

\begin{document}
\huge
Test

\bfseries
Test

\scshape
Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is [a known bug](https://github.com/pgundlach/linuxlibertine/issues/3) -- which actually was reported with almost the very same code you're using here?!

Comment: Haha, funny coincidence. I meant to use the `minimal` document class first, but `\huge` didn't work, so I settled with `standalone` instead.

Comment: That's why we don't use `minimal` for minimals `:)`. As long as you're not providing an image, I'd even choose `article` over `standalone`, since the former is more basic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
\usepackage{libertine}
```

instead. With a current TeXLive or MiKTeX it should work. In both cases you can update your system if it is not up-to-date with the package manager. If you are using the TL from Ubuntu or another Linux distro then update the package `libertine` from ctan, eg: http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/fonts/libertine.zip (not all mirrors provide a zip). After installing move the old `libertine-legacy` and `libertineotf` to `/tmp` or elsewhere. Then run `sudo texhash` and `sudo updmap --enable Map=libertine.map`

Alternetively you can use Libertine without using a package:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont%[SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]
     {Linux Libertine O}
 \begin{document}     
...
```

then you also get bold Small Caps.

[image]

Comment: My `texlive` is from July 2012, so I think it is not recent enough yet. When using `libertine` instead of `libertineotf`I am getting missing font errors:
`LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/fxl/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.`

Comment: @mSSM: Yes, the Linux Libertine packages have been in an awkward state of transition since about Nov 2011, when the developers decided to drop pdfLaTeX support. Some people, including Herbert, thankfully made the effort to maintain a package that works with pdfLaTeX -- but it's been in a process of settling in, and there were a few different approaches. The latest (which Herbert is probably referring to) is just one or two weeks old.

Comment: @mSSM: I edited my answer

Comment: Can you remind me what the advantage of using `libertineotf` over loading libertine with `fontspec` is to begin with?

Comment: @mSSM: `libertineotf` is deprecated and `libertine` tries to support _all_ engines: LuaTeX, XeTeX and PDFTeX. And, of course, it fixes a bug of `libertineotf`. However it is still possible to define the font setting by yourself.

Comment: I just installed the latest TeXlive snapshot with TeXlive-core 28723, and the `libertine` package works really well now. Thanks!