# \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} uses pfb files instead of otf

Tags: fonts, miktex, fontspec, libertine, opentype

(This is sort of a follow-up to [libertineotf and xelatex - bold smallcaps broken?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84195/4012), based on a problem that I had noticed earlier, but hadn't put my finger on.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}% 1
%   \setmainfont{LinLibertine_R_0.otf}% 2
%   \usepackage{libertineotf}% 3
\begin{document}
Foo bar. \textsc{Foo bar \textbf{baz!}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Unexpectedly, this file doesn't use the otf Linux Libertine O files in `C:\Windows\Fonts\`, but the pfb files in my texmf tree (cf. log snippets below). I presume this is why the small caps don't work as described in [Herbert's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84196/4012), and also why doing any OpenType magic à la `\addfontfeauture` doesn't work either.

I'm not quite sure where the problem is coming from. Variant 2, which calls the otf font directly, runs, but doesn't use small caps; I assume that's because this font file is too specific for `fontspec` to automatically find the small caps font, so that I'd have to specify the file with the `SmallCapsFont` option manually. Variant 3 works pretty well, but as outlined in the question linked above, the calling of small caps is buggy there (and I want to solve the problem, not circumvent it).

As for background, I'm using MiKTeX 2.9, all up-to-date; and I have version 5.3 of the Linux Libertine fonts installed in `C:\Windows\Fonts\` (independently from LaTeX, these are the ones I would've expected `fontspec` to use).

Some seemingly relevant bits from the log file (of variant 1):

```
Requested font "Linux Libertine O" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/libertine/LinLibertine
O.pfb
Requested font "Linux Libertine O/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/libertine/LinLibertine
O.pfb
```

[and a number of similar lines, but then:]

```
Requested font "Linux Libertine O/BI/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Windows/Fonts/LinLibertine_RB.otf
Requested font "Linux Libertine O/BI/BI/ICU" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Windows/Fonts/LinLibertine_RB.otf
```

I don't really have a specific question, other than: **What's going on here, and how can I fix it?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some reason XeTeX is finding the Type1 fonts first<sup>1</sup>, you can tell FontConfig not to use Type1 fonts by blacklistling them by putting something like this in your local FontConfig configuration file (see [How to make XeLaTeX recognize linked fonts with Windows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45478/729) for more details).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <selectfont>
    <rejectfont>
      <glob>C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/libertine/*</glob>
    </rejectfont>
  </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
```

You can even blacklist all Type1 fonts in `TEXMF` tree by using `C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/*` instead.

<sup>1</sup> But not essentially using them for typesetting, `fontspec` loads the font first to collect some info about it, before loading it for “real”. To see the actual fonts that went into the PDF, try running `xelatex` with the option `--output-driver="xdvipdfmx -v"` to get some verbose output.

***Update***: This is more or less fixed now in XeTeX; TrueType/OpenType are given high priority over Type1, so it should be fixed in TeX Live 2013 (and the equivalent MiKTeX update).

Comment: Thanks! Several things: In the place Leo described, I only found `fonts.config.in` (note the `.in`), no `localfonts.config`. Creating a `localfonts.config` with or without `.in`, with the content you proposed, followed by updating the FNDB, refreshing the formats, deleting the auxiliary files, and recompiling didn't change anything. Also, running `xelatex` with the option you described (copy-pasted) returns `xelatex: Invalid command-line option` \\ `xelatex: Data: unknown option`.

Comment: @doncherry: sorry, I don’t use MiKTeX (nor Windows), and don’t know much about its specifics, for FontConfig you would want to run the equivalent of `fc-cache` command line tool. No idea why XeTeX option is not recognized, probably options are handled differently than TeX Live implementation.

Comment: The `xelatex` works with `"` instead of `'`. I'm now playing around with `fc-cache`, which is new to me.

Comment: I created the `localfonts.config`,  ran `fc-cache -r -v`, but the output included the line `C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/libertine: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs`. No progress in the output. While I don't think the log of the compilation will be particularly enlightening, here it is: http://pastebin.com/n5cW11Dh

Comment: @doncherry: Try using `.conf` instead of `.config`, I don’t think FontConfig recognizes the later.

Comment: Sorry, typo, I was using `.conf` of course.

Comment: Alright, I fixed it. While I didn't find the `localfonts[2].conf` files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\fontconfig\config`, they were in `C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config` and `C:\Users\doncherry\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config`. Inserting the lines you suggested in _the latter_ of these two solved the problem (only the former didn't help, and both isn't necessary). I'll let Leo know, perhaps we can improve the other answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Khaled, if you (or @Speravir) can make any sense of these different folder configurations, please edit them into the answer. I wouldn't really feel like I know what I was talking about. (Then we could probably delete most, if not all of these comments, as Spervir suggested in chat.)