# Hyphenate typewriter / avoid overfull \hboxes in code, using fontspec and XeTeX

Tags: xetex, boxes, fontspec, hyphenation, typewriter

I would like to avoid overfull `\hbox`es as a result of inline code, inserted with `\textt{foo}` or `\ttfamily`, e.g. in this MWE:

```
% compile with xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=4cm, showframe]{geometry}% to force hyphenation
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\setlength{\overfullrule}{1mm}
\begin{document}
{\ttfamily Bla \textbackslash newcommand\{\textbackslash foo\}\{bar\}
\textbackslash setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]\{DejaVu Sans Mono\}

For regular words, it works supercalifragilisticexpialidociously (or more like kind of ok),
but real code is tricky.}
\end{document}
```

[image: xelatex output]

I'd like to have hyphenation points (manual instruction is ok) between `Match` and `Lowercase`, and between `{\foo}` and `{bar}`. However, I don't ever want a hyphen to appear at hyphenation points (in typewriter text).

I've tried `\-`, which doesn't work (`babelshorthands` is not available for `english`). I also know about the `fontspec` option `HyphenChar`, but I don't know how to tell it "no hyphenation character, but hyphentation" (space / `32` is not an option because it appears in the OCR layer of the pdf; `None` would disable hyphenation altogether). I guess these might both be traces of the solution, but I can't figure out how to make use of them.

Comment: P.S.: Compiling my MWE (minus `polyglossia`) with LuaLaTeX results in surprisingly different output, especially the `MatchLowercase` part: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IGOHK.png (MiKTeX 2.9). Is that just a difference that's to be expected, or a bug on the side of LuaTeX/XeTeX/`fontspec`? I.e. would this be of interest to any of the development teams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first attempt uses a space character as hyphenation character, however I realized later that the OP explicitely had said it was a no-go. So there is a second attempt below which does not use the space (or other) character.

---

The following works with me (I commented out the DejaVu Sans Mono line as for some reason it does not work on my installation, tried to add ExternalLocation as option but this did not solve it and I don't use often enough XeTeX or LuaTeX to investigate further the reason of the problem)

```
% compile with xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=4cm, showframe]{geometry}% to force hyphenation
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%    \setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\setlength{\overfullrule}{1mm}
\begin{document}
{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font32 
Bla \textbackslash newcommand\{\textbackslash foo\}\-\{bar\}
\textbackslash setmonofont[Scale=\-Match\-Lowercase]\{DejaVu Sans Mono\}

For regular words, it works supercalifragilisticexpialidociously (or more like
kind of ok), but real code is tricky.}
\end{document}
```

[image: hyphenation with space as hyphen]

Note that the space is used as hyphen character. And I added a few `\-` to the code.

---

I read now your 'space is not an option' it probably disqualifies my attempt! So here is a second try:

```
% compile with xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=4cm, showframe]{geometry}% to force hyphenation
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=usmax]{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%    \setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\setlength{\overfullrule}{1mm}
\begin{document}
{\ttfamily\def\-{\discretionary{}{}{}}%
Bla \textbackslash newcommand\{\textbackslash foo\}\-\{bar\}
\textbackslash setmonofont[Scale=\-Match\-Lowercase]\{DejaVu Sans Mono\}

For regular words, it works supercalifra\-gilisticexpialidociously (or more like
kind of ok), but real code is tricky.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I had to add explicitely a breaking point in the text part.

Comment: Precisely `:)`. I mean, if there's no better way, I'll do that, but I was hoping for a better way. Btw, `\hyphenchar` seems to be equivalent to `fontspec`'s `HyphenChar` option. As for your trouble with DejaVu Mono: It might be [Weird spacing with DejaVu Sans Mono with MiKTeX's XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84706) (the solution to which I still have to write up), or perhaps you don't have the font on your system at all.

Comment: @doncherry: I updated my answer! I might well not have the font on my system, but not using enough XeTeX I did not investigate the issue.

Comment: @doncherry: ok I overcame my laziness, and indeed on my mac os, there is no DejaVu among the system wide fonts, and I found no opentype version in the texlive tree either (but of course I already used it as type1 font). Apart from that, although my `\discretionary{}{}{}` seems to go towards the solution, I do not understand yet how to at the same time have the automatic hyphenation activated.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. My version of `fontspec` enables hyphenatation of typewriter text. So you only need a special `\discretionary` command for the code parts. (I wouldn't redefine `\-` but use some other command. german babel e.g. use the shorthand `""`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The problem seems to be how to have the TeX automatic hyphenation activated but without any hyphenation character at broken words at lines endings.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you add an answer showing how you would solve this problem?