# TeX Live 2013: TrueType fonts

Tags: fonts, texlive, opentype, truetype, type1

In the [list of changes in TeX Live 2013](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-810009.2) it says

> Prefer TrueType/OpenType fonts to Type1 when the names are the same.

But are not Type1 fonts *better* since they are **vector** fonts?

Can someone clarify why TrueType/OpenType are better?

Comment: TrueType/OpenType ones are also vector fonts.

Comment: There is a lot of detail on the various font formats out there (obvious candidate is WikiPedia). I wonder what a 'good' answer here needs other than saying what @Leo has already said with appropriate links to details of the formats.

Comment: All the three are vector font formats, however OpenType/TrueType are rich formats that can support many features and languages than Type 1 fonts can do, more ever this change concerns XeTeX which can utilize these features, not any other part of TeX Live. This change was in response to issues like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84223/729.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Yes TrueType fonts are also vector fonts. I tend to associate TrueType fonts with MS Office. 1 vote up for everyone.

Answer (score 10):

All three font types are vector font formats, however OpenType/TrueType are rich formats that can support many more features and languages than Type 1 fonts can do, moreover, this change concerns XeTeX which can utilize these features, not any other part of TeX Live. This change was in response to issues like the following question:

- [\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} uses pfb files instead of otf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84223/729).